# Mirror API custom menu and custom properties

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

In my app I have added custom menu items to user timeline items. I am creating the custom menus in iteration. Is there any way to append the custom properties to the custom menu item? , so that I can know which menu item is clicked.

ere is my code for custom menu,

```
// And custom actions
List<MenuValue> menuValues = new ArrayList<MenuValue>();
menuValues.add(new MenuValue().setIconUrl(WebUtil.buildUrl(req, "/static/images/drill.png")).setDisplayName("Found"));
menuItemList.add(new MenuItem().setValues(menuValues).setId("found").setAction("CUSTOM"));

timelineItem.setMenuItems(menuItemList);
timelineItem.setNotification(new NotificationConfig().setLevel("DEFAULT"));
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already attaching a property to the menu item with the `setId()` method. The value in the id is ignored by Glass except to send it back to you when this menu item is selected. You can put anything you want here (within reason - there is a limit of a few hundred characters).

So, given your example above, if the menu item is selected, you'd get a notification looking something like this:

```
{ 
  "collection": "timeline",
  "itemId": "8a84302a-1da7-46f2-ac72-2c008fce2b4b",
  "operation": "UPDATE",
  "userToken": "12345678901234567890",
  "verifyToken": "shibboleet",
  "userActions": [ 
    { 
      "type": "CUSTOM", 
      "payload": "found" 
    }
  ]
}
```

You would examine the `userActions.payload` field and take action based on this.